# Do I need to change my gem path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, homebrew

I'm trying to install rails to my machine, but keep hitting the same problem, I've installed ruby `2.2.0` and set it via `rbenv` as `global`, `ruby -v` shows correctly

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin14]
```

but when I try to install rails I get the following error;

```
$ gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

I've read a few places that I shouldn't use `sudo gem install rails` if I don't know what I'm upto as I could cause issues fumbling around!

My question is should I/can I change my path so I don't have this issue with permissions? If so where?

Comment: Run `which gem` and see which version of ruby that's running in? Chances are `gem` is running through system ruby. If that's the case, make sure you've added the rbenv init to your shell: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#basic-github-checkout

Comment: Try running this `echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile`. Hope it helps.

Comment: An easy solution if you're open to it is changing from using `rvm` to using `ruby-install`. In my experience, RVM causes many path problems, and also isn't needed any more now that there's `bundler`, `ruby-install`, and `chruby`.